# C#: Using methods from a library

Tags: c#, class

I'm working on a C# project. I have a library of classes in which I have classes that contain methods. My library is called `MyLib`

I'm trying to use these methods in a Windows Form. However, they are not detected. I wrote `using MyLib;` on the preamble of the Form. I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I tried to change a lot of things and none works.

The error I'm getting is:

> The name 'openDataBase' does not exist in the current context.

Thans on beforehand! I'm pretty sure it will be a little mistake but I'm getting nervous already since I can't find it.

P.S: The class contains this method (among others):

```
public OleDbConnection openDataBase(String name)
    {
        OleDbConnection cnx;
        String fullName = name + ".sdf";
        string cnxStr = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5; Data Source=" + fullName + ";Persist Security Info=False;";
        cnx = new OleDbConnection(cnxStr);
        cnx.Open();
        return cnx;
    }
```

Comment: How and where do you call the method?

Comment: how do you call that method

Comment: make sure your top level class, MyLib is public as well.

Comment: Also, if the MyLib class is built for a newer .net runtime than your program, it will not work.  Make sure your project is the same version (or newer) than MyLib.

Comment: do you have a reference to your library from your project?

Comment: You should add a Project reference (from the Solution section)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx

Answer (score 3):

From what little I can see from your code, my guess is that you're trying to call openDataBase without referencing the class it's found in (this can be the wrong idea though, since you're not showing you call it).

Assuming the method is found in MyClass:

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
OleDbConnection connection = myclass.openDataBase(name);
```

Another option is that you've forgotten to reference the library. Right-click the References folder in your solution explorer and click "Add reference". then browse to the library and add it as a reference.

http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/mswinswdev/ms_csharp_name_does_not_exist_in_current_context.htm shows a number of reasons why you might get this error.

Comment: if you are right then he could not get that error because the project will not compile...

Comment: @giammin He's not saying that he's getting the error during execution. the error he got is something that only happens during compile time, so if he gets that error, it's because of compilation errors.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs If you were right, the error would be MyClass does not exist. If he can see MyClass but not MyClass.openDataBase(), then he is obviously not missing a refrence.

Comment: Thanks to you all! It's solved already. What was happening is that I forgot what @NateKerkhofs said.

I wrote `OleDbConnection connection = openDataBase('userDB');`

I was missing `myclass.openDataBase('userDB')`

Thanks, I was so stuck...